# How to groupby two fields and set index as one of the two fields. Pandas, Python-3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I'm new to Stack Overflow so any community best practices are welcome too.

```
#aggregate rides and average of fares
combo_grouped_df =combo_df.groupby(['city','type'])
#combo_grouped_df.set_index('city') does not work! 

combo_grouped_df.head()

avg_fare =combo_grouped_df['fare'].mean()
total_rides =combo_grouped_df['ride_id'].count()
city_type = combo_grouped_df['type']

summary_df = pd.DataFrame({"Average Fare": avg_fare,
                        "Number of Rides": total_rides,
                        "Type": combo_grouped_df['type']}) # how to get type in this dict?????
summary_df.head()}
```

Results in:

```
                        Average Fare  Number of Rides  \
city          type                                      
Amandaburgh   Urban        24.641667               18   
Barajasview   Urban        25.332273               22   
Barronchester Suburban     36.422500               16   
Bethanyland   Suburban     32.956111               18   
Bradshawfurt  Rural        40.064000               10   

                                                                     Type  
city          type                                                         
Amandaburgh   Urban     ((Amandaburgh, Urban), [Urban, Urban, Urban, U...  
Barajasview   Urban     ((Barajasview, Urban), [Urban, Urban, Urban, U...  
Barronchester Suburban  ((Barronchester, Suburban), [Suburban, Suburba...  
Bethanyland   Suburban  ((Bethanyland, Suburban), [Suburban, Suburban,...  
Bradshawfurt  Rural     ((Bradshawfurt, Rural), [Rural, Rural, Rural, ...
```

I'd like to move the goupby 'type' index to the columns where 'Type' is. Or get 'Type' to display as a single string (example 'Urban') with no brackets.

`df.set_index = False` does not work because I want to keep the 'city' index . 
Groupby of a groupby does not seem to work either. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit for clarity: I wish to groupby 'city' and use it as the index.  I want to have 'type' in the dataframe and not in the index.  Currently 'Type' returns a list of values that are essentially the same value repeated.

Comment: `df.reset_index(level=1)` to remove that level from the index.

Comment: Your question is not very clear but I guess you need groupby with age and reset_index. Something like, combo_df.groupby(['city','type']).agg({'fare': 'mean', 'ride_id': 'count'}).reset_index()

Comment: `combo_grouped_df.reset_index(level=1)` gives the error ` Cannot access callable attribute 'reset_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`

Comment: apply that after your aggregation function, not to the grouped object, as indicated in the second comment.

Comment: `combo_df.groupby(['city','type']).agg({'fare': 'mean', 'ride_id': 'count'}).reset_index(level=1)` worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is:

```
import pandas as pd

# Group it
group_df = combo_df.groupby(['city','type'])
# Aggregate it
aggregated_df = group_df.agg({'fare': 'mean', 'ride_id': 'count'})
# Reset index (only type)
summary_df = aggregated_df.reset_index(level=1)
```